# D3.js and NVD3.js, which to use and when

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

What are the benefits/drawbacks of using D3.js vs NVD3.js?

(some points that interest me most: Isn't it better to stick just with NVD3.js if it is better in any way? Why use D3.js? Is it that NVD3.js just provides a set of sample graphs and that's why we might use NVD3.js if we find precisely the same thing as we need in their examples? And d3.js should be used when we need a very specific thing that has not been done with NVD3.js?)

Comment: If your requirement is a simple Barchart or line chart pie chart or anything in the example pool http://nvd3.org/examples/index.html i would go with NVD3..._reason:(less lines of code)_
If I have to make any chart other than the one's in nvd3 example pool I have no choice but to go with d3 ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would look into using nvd3.js or similar D3 based libraries as it makes the chart component reusable and intuitive. Here is an article that helped with the decision from Mike Bostock, who created D3, https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/. If there is a use case where you need to implement something that is not available in nvd3, you can try to do that  using the reusable pattern suggested in the previously mentioned article.